# Finding the first duplicate character in the string Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to call the first duplicate character in my string in Ruby. 
I have defined an input string using gets.

How do I call the first duplicate character in the string?

This is my code so far.

```
string = "#{gets}"
print string
```

How do I call a character from this string?

Edit 1:

This is the code I have now where my output is coming out to me No duplicates 26 times. I think my if statement is wrongly written.

```
string "abcade"
puts string
for i in ('a'..'z')
if string =~ /(.)\1/
puts string.chars.group_by{|c| c}.find{|el| el[1].size >1}[0]
else
puts "no duplicates"
end
end
```

My second puts statement works but with the for and if loops, it returns no duplicates 26 times whatever the string is.

Comment: Do you want to know the first duplicate character or the index of where it occurs? Does `tester` count as duplicated since it has two `e` characters, or are you intending to find things like `billing`?

Comment: You'd need to iterate through the string, keeping a set of already-found characters, and stop iterating as soon as the set contains the current character. One way to access string chars is using array index notation, e.g., `s[0]` etc. Another is to iterate using `each_char`. There are many options.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code generates a syntax error error "`undefined method 'string' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`". Perhaps that's because you didn't copy your code into the question correctly? "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Convert to array and use `detect`? see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s.chars.map { |c| [c, s.count(c)] }.drop_while{|i| i[1] <= 1}.first[0]
```

With the refined form from [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) :

```
s.each_char.find { |c| s.count(c) > 1 }
```

Comment: Consider the simplification: `s.each_char.find { |c| s.count(c) > 1 }`. Note that `s.each_char` is an enumerator, which is more efficient than the (temporary) array `s.chars`. In any event, this is a solution to the second interpretation of the question I gave in my answer. +1.

Answer (score 5):

The following returns the *index* of the first duplicate character:

```
the_string =~ /(.)\1/
```

Example:

```
'1234556' =~ /(.)\1/
=> 4
```

To get the duplicate character itself, use `$1`:

```
$1
=> "5"
```

Example usage in an `if` statement:

```
if my_string =~ /(.)\1/
  # found duplicate; potentially do something with $1
else
  # there is no match
end
```

Comment: How does this work?  What part of that regex identifies duplication?

Comment: I don't want the index of the string but the character itself. So for instance for your string I would want the output to be 5.

Comment: @ShailiParikh I specifically asked what you wanted in the comments above. It really would've helped to have said that up front.

Comment: why the result is `4` not `5` ?

Comment: @ShailiParikh the character is saved in the variable $1

Comment: @R_O_R Because that's the index, not the character.

Comment: Shaili, that's a minor change to David's answer. If `r` is his regular expression, the first duplicate character is  `the_string[r]` or `the_string[the_string =~ r]` (or even simpler: see David's edit).

Comment: @R_O_R so the index number starts with 0 right. The index for 5 is 4 since it is duplicated.

Comment: @JaredBeck the (.) part of the regex matches any character and captures it in $1 and the \1 part of the regex matches any duplicate of $1

Comment: @davidrac Is there any way I can make this an if statement and also return something if there are no duplicates?

Comment: @ShailiParikh yes. In case there is no duplication, the first expression will return nil:
'123456' =~ /(.)\1/
=> nil
so you may write something like:
`if my_string =~ /(.)\1/
  # do something with $1
else
  # there is no match
end`
sorry for the bad indentation, see my edit for proper one

Comment: @davidrac I tried to do it but I am getting the output to be No duplicates 26 times. Please check out my edit.

Comment: @ShailiParikh my answer is about finding two adjacent duplicate letters. I guess from your code that you are looking for something else...

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Mostly just disturbed ;)

Comment: @davidrac check out the code by Yevgeniy Anfilofyev. How do I put if in it?

Answer (score 2):

Below method might be useful to find the first word in a string

```
def firstRepeatedWord(string)
  h_data = Hash.new(0)
  string.split(" ").each{|x| h_data[x] +=1}
  h_data.key(h_data.values.max)
end
```

Comment: You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question can be interpreted in either of two ways (neither involving the first *pair* of adjacent characters that are the same) and offer solutions to each.

**Find the first character in the string that is preceded by the same character**

I don't believe we can use a regex for this (but would love to be proved wrong). I would use the method suggested in a comment by @DaveNewton:

```
require 'set'

def first_repeat_char(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(Set.new) { |c,s| return c unless s.add?(c) }
  nil
end

first_repeat_char("abcdebf") #=> b
first_repeat_char("abcdcbe") #=> c
first_repeat_char("abcdefg") #=> nil
```

**Find the first character in the string that appears more than once**

```
r = /
    (.) # match any character in capture group #1
    .*  # match any character zero of more times
    ?   # do the preceding lazily
    \K  # forget everything matched so far
    \1  # match the contents of capture group 1
    /x

"abcdebf"[r] #=> b
"abccdeb"[r] #=> b
"abcdefg"[r] #=> nil
```

This regex is fine, but produces the warning, "regular expression has redundant nested repeat operator '*'". You can disregard the warning or suppress it by doing something clunky, like:

```
r = /([^#{0.chr}]).*?\K\1/
```

where `([^#{0.chr}])` means "match any character other than `0.chr` in capture group 1".

Note that a positive lookbehind cannot be used here, as they cannot contain variable-length matches (i.e., `.*`).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably make your `string` an array and use `detect`. This should return the first char where the count is > 1.

```
string.split("").detect {|x| string.count(x) > 1}
```

Comment: Cool - feel free to mark this as correct and upvote if this works :). Also if you expect spaces in `#{gets}` you can just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use *positive lookahead* with `String#[]` method :

```
"abcccddde"[/(.)(?=\1)/] #=> c
```

Comment: Alas, @Davidrac's solution achieve's the same result, but is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:

```
str = "abcdeff"
p str.chars.group_by{|c| c}.find{|el| el[1].size > 1}[0]
```

prints "f"

Comment: I am also trying to output a value when there are no duplicates in the string. How do I make this an if statement?